# Using paste command to join with multiple character delimiter

Tags: linux, unix, shell, paste

I have a file which gets generated based on the arguments and it has the following contents.

```
2012-12-31
2012-12-30
2012-12-29
```

Now, these are actually date partitions for hive query. So, I want to use them in my hive query where I specify each of these partitions in `WHERE` clause. Something like below

```
 WHERE log_date IN ('2012-12-31','2012-12-30', '2012-12-29')
```

So, I am looking the output from `paste` as

```
 2012-12-31','2012-12-30','2012-12-29
```

I am using the following, but I think the `-d` parameter is a list of delimiter and not one complete delimiter.

```
paste -sd"','" datefile
```

Any idea how can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using sed and paste together:

```
$ sed "s/.*/'&'/" file | paste -sd,
'2012-12-31','2012-12-30','2012-12-29'
```

Comment: Nice. I too used something similar.  I added a single delimiter with ````paste```` and then used ````sed```` to replace it with actual one. ````paste -sd"," datefile | sed "s/\,/'\,'/g"````

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
echo  "WHERE log_date IN ('$(sed -e :a -e "$!N; s/\n/','/; ta" datefile)')"
```